# How can I to test an Internet connection with Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to check with my application when there is an internet connection in order to send emails, it's happening to me that every time I send an email it's lost because there is some internet failure.

Also, how can I put these emails in a queue of pending so that once there is connection are sent ?.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question seems to be broader.

Comment: Thank you @KarthickRamesh, yes, I've an application in Django, but it happens that every time I send an email and for some reason there isn't internet connection, that email delivery is lost, I'd like it to be placed on hold and once there is an internet connection are sent from automatic way (As do the gmail, hotmail, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add you emails to the background tasks. Then you can use a background worker like celery or redis-queue for executing them.

Celery: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Redis Queue: https://python-rq.org/docs/